# Wrapping XML document in one-element JSON using XSLT 1.0

Tags: json, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to transform an XML document to be in single-line and wrap it in a one-element JSON. Using XSLT 1.0

The problem is, XSL generates double quotes in the xmlns definitions so the resulting JSON is invalid.

This is my input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<otm:Transmission xmlns:otm='http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm/transmission/v6.4' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
  <otm:TransmissionHeader/>
  <otm:TransmissionBody>
    <otm:GLogXMLElement>
      <otm:Invoice>
        <otm:Payment>
          <otm:PaymentHeader>
            <otm:DomainName>CompanyX</otm:DomainName>
            <otm:TransactionCode>EX</otm:TransactionCode>
            <otm:InvoiceDate>
              <otm:GLogDate>20220414000000</otm:GLogDate>
            </otm:InvoiceDate>
          </otm:PaymentHeader>
        </otm:Payment>
      </otm:Invoice>
    </otm:GLogXMLElement>
  </otm:TransmissionBody>
</otm:Transmission>
```

This is what I'm getting:

```
{"jsonElement":"<otm:Transmission xmlns:otm="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm/transmission/v6.4" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><otm:TransmissionHeader/><otm:TransmissionBody><otm:GLogXMLElement><otm:Invoice><otm:Payment><otm:PaymentHeader><otm:DomainName>CompanyX</otm:DomainName><otm:TransactionCode>EX</otm:TransactionCode><otm:InvoiceDate><otm:GLogDate>20220414000000</otm:GLogDate></otm:InvoiceDate></otm:PaymentHeader></otm:Payment></otm:Invoice></otm:GLogXMLElement></otm:TransmissionBody></otm:Transmission>"}
```

The XSL that I use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:otm='http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm/transmission/v6.4'>
<xsl:output method="text" indent="no" suppress-indentation="otm:Transmission"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
{"jsonElement":"<xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>"}
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | *">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you can see, the JSON is invalid due to double quotes in the xmlns definitons.

I tried several approaches and I am not able to get rid of the double quotes. In the input, they are single quotes but XSL is generating them differently.

What would be the best approach to have a valid JSON result?
The XML in the JSON has to be 1:1 copy of the input but transformed into a single line and I can only use XSLT 1.0

Comment: 1:1 represetation in formatting or content? Try to encode the xml to a base64 string and decode in on the receiving side

Comment: @MarcStroebel it has to remain unchanged, except for removing new lines and identation. Unfortunately, I have no control over what happens on the receiving side and they expect UTF-8 encoding, so base64 is not going to work. Great idea though!

Comment: Which XSLT (1.0?) processor is that? The use of `suppress-indentation` suggests it is rather an XSLT 2 or 3 processor.

Comment: XSLT is not a good tool for this. XSLT does not even see the original document. It works on the parsed input tree and then serializes the result. You have practically no control over the way the serializer works - and doing your own serialization is a lot of work (see: http://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/). Even then you cannot guarantee the result will be an exact copy of the original XML.

Comment: I don't see how `xsl:output method="text"` would give the result you show.

Comment: I was using this tool to test the XSL: [freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html](https://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html)

Answer (score 1):

An XSLT 1.0 processor is going to reject the `suppress-indentation` attribute, and it's going to output the text of the source document without markup. Like @MartinHonnen, I don't see how any XSLT processor can give you the output you claim to be getting.

In XSLT 3.0 you can do

```
<xsl:output method="json">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:map key="'jsonElement'"
           select="serialize(., map{'method':'xml'})"/>
</xsl:template>
```